# Genesis Framework - How to get logo and hamburger menu on same line on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using the basic Genesis Child Theme, and would like to figure out how to get my website logo to shrink on mobile to the degree that it will allow the logo and menu to sit on the same line, and thus reduce the header space.

I've noticed that with the header as big as it is, it's difficult to enter one's information into my contact form, especially given that the keyboard appears from the bottom as well.

The issue can be seen here: www.vacounseling.com/contact-directions/

Any solutions to this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

EDIT: Thanks leoap, I believe this is the code.

```
/* Site Header
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.site-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding: 0 30px;
}

/* Title Area
--------------------------------------------- */

.title-area {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.wp-custom-logo .title-area {
    max-width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wp-custom-logo .title-area img {
    width: auto;
}

.site-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:focus,
.site-title a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.site-description,
.wp-custom-logo .site-title {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;}
```

Comment: Hello John, and welcome to stackoverflow. can you show us some of your code, like the header code and css?